# How to make a clustercomputer testcode with python? (RPI)

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, cluster-computing, supercomputers

I made a clustercomputer for a school project. Only i am having some problems with making a code that uses all eight Raspberry pi's.

https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-Raspberry-Pi-SuperComputer/ 
This is the base i used to make it.
running:

```
mpiexec -f machinefile -n 8 hostname
```

output:
all the hostnames of the Pi's.
the machinefile contains all the IP's of the Pi's.
Running a program:

```
mpiexec -f machinefile -n 8 python test.py
```

output: It just runs the program seperatly on all Pi's.

How can i make a code or a command that makes the Pi's split the load of the program?

My goal is to have all 8 Pi's working together but not doing the same calculations and thereby speeding the proces up significantly.

Comment: You should use some message passing library to be able to synchronize the processes. Take a look at [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I really don't know how to sync the processes

Comment: You can get all the processes in sync with a barrier (`MPI_barrier`). Check the docs of [one of the implementations](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)